# Client socket is not receiving a string

Tags: java, sockets

I have created a simple client server socket program and sending a string a|b|c|* and the client is not recieving it. The client is on another machine.

Server Code.

```
String format = "a|b|c|*";
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(2222);
System.out.println("Server Started.");

while (true) {              
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    System.out.println("Connection accepted.");
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ps.println(format);             
    ps.flush();
    System.out.println("Format sent.");
}
```

Client Side

```
try {
    Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.71", 2222);
    // step 3: Get I/O streams
    InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String format = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(format);
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

When I create a client on the same machine then it is receiving the string, and when i pass this string to another machine client it doesn't receive it.

Comment: What does happen? Is there and exception? Does it connect but not get any data?

Comment: @Peter,yeah exactly it does connect but not getting any data.

Comment: When you use telnet to the host and port, on the same box and the other box, what do you get? `telnet 192.168.0.71 2222`

Comment: and there is no as such exception. It does receive the data when i run a client on my machine. and when i run a client on another machine not getting a data.

Comment: when i telnet, it shows a string which i have sent from the server.

Comment: I would make sure the client really is connecting by adding a line before the readLine with `System.out.println("Connected to " +s);`

Comment: @Peter, yes peter it is connecting.

Comment: Connected to Socket[addr=/192.168.0.71,port=2222,localport=2873]

Comment: And you are seeing `Format sent.` on the server?

Comment: Try using socket.setTcpNodelay(true);

Comment: What happens when you close the socket on the server. (You should be doing this anyway but it shouldn't make a difference)

Comment: @soulcheck, that avoids a <40 ms delay. I assume he is waiting longer than that.

Comment: yes i am seeing Format sent on the server

Comment: I am not closing the socket. because i thought that it might be a reason, if socket is closed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey dunno, saw in another answer and i thought it was worth a shot, since OP connects, flushes and receives response with telnet.

Comment: A close is more likely to force the data to be sent.  It calls `flush()` first.  However, I agree that what you are doing should work. I can only assume some code or something you haven't mentioned is causing a problem.

Comment: Could it simply be the case that client is behind a firewall?

Comment: @DejanLekic If it wa,s OP wouldn't be able to telnet to his server.

Comment: I'm not sure that a telnet has been tried from the remote machine to the server.  Can you try that @Java_NewBie?  Also, could the server socket be binding to the wrong interface?  If you run the server, what does this show from the terminal: `netstat -an | grep 2222`

Answer (score 0):

So I tried your code on two of my boxes and remote connections worked fine.  A bunch of good comments but I thought I'd write out an answer with some things to try:

1. It's been implied that you've been able to telnet locally to the server and see the format string.  Fine.  Are you also been able to use telnet from a remote client to the server and *also* see the format string?
2. If the remote telnet does not work then I'd check if there is a firewall or otherwise a routing issue.  Can you ping the server from the client?
3. Another reason why telnet might not work is that your server may be binding to the wrong port.  The default is to bind to all interfaces but just to be sure, you should check.  If you are on a unix box or OSX then you can use the `netstat` command to see what ports you are binding to.  The following output shows that the server is bound to `*` which means all interfaces.

   ```
   $ netstat -an | grep 2222     
   tcp46      0      0  *.2222                 *.*                    LISTEN
   ```
4. If nothing else helps then realize that if you have a telnet connected, it will block all other telnets and clients from connecting since you are not closing the socket on the server.

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: now it is saying that unable to connect to the destination ipAddress:portNmumber

Comment: If telnet is saying that they some sort of firewall is in the way or your server is not working.  Start your server, try telnet locally, try telnet off box but on close network, try telnet remotely.