# Not Receving a String in sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I have posted a question two days back here is the link.
[Client socket is not receiving a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269324/client-socket-is-not-receiving-a-string)
I am still having this same issue. I am getting these warnings e.g. connection time out. unable to connect to destination. When i send a message to the client after the connection extablished it disconnects. When i telnet it also gives me this warning. "coould not open connection to the host." I am just stuck into this.

Comment: If telnet doesn't work across the network but does locally, you have a network problem.  There is nothing you can do in Java until you can reliably connect to a service the same as connecting locally.

Comment: now when i telnet it shows a string which i have to sent, and on the very next line it says "Connection to the host lost."

Comment: That is fine if the server sends one line of text and disconnects i.e. calls `close()`

Comment: @Peter...then peter why the string is not showing up in cmd console without using telnet.

Comment: I would try connecting locally on the machine with the failing client, and I would try swapping the client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the same port using telnet as in your application? (Just checking - I sometimes forget to specify the port).

"Could not open connection to the host" can indicate a number of problems, such as a firewall not being open, the host being down, or an incorrect DNS or hosts file entry.

Peter Lawrey is correct in that if your telnet connection setting is identical to your application, then it isn't a problem with your code :)

Comment: now when i telnet it shows a string which i have to sent, and on the very next line it says "Connection to the host lost."